# Initializing array of structs strange behavior

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I am using an array of structs and then set up the elements like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _point {
    char s;
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
} point;

point* vehicle;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* 26 Vehicles */
    vehicle = malloc(26*sizeof(point*));
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        vehicle[i].s = ' ';
    }

    /* Print already existing vehicles */
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (vehicle[i].s != ' ') {
            printf("%c: x=%d y=%d\n", vehicle[i].s, vehicle[i].x, vehicle[i].y);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE**: this is not the actual code (which is too big to post) but the set up of the array and `structs` is the same.

As you can see, I set every `vehicle[i].s` to the space character, but the loop prints the following (not it this example code but in my actual code):

> ```
> : x=32215344 y=0
> P: x=0 y=33
> : x=2105376 y=0
> ```

**Question**: how can it be that after the first loop, some elements are modified in the "background" without assigning them in the code? Or can some other malloc operations overwrite/reallocate the memory?

Comment: A typical beginner's error:  `malloc(26*sizeof(point*))`-> `malloc(26*sizeof(point))`

Comment: Or, `vehicle = malloc(26*sizeof(*vehicle));`

Comment: Just a suggestion: type `point *vehicle` instead of `point* vehicle` because this is what declarations mean in C: `base_type thing_that_gives_base_type ;` This helps me to think clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, as I see it is in

```
 vehicle = malloc(26*sizeof(point*));
```

you're allocating memory for the pointer-to-the-data-type type, whereas you should be allocating for the data type itself.

To elaborate, you want to allocate memory for 26 elements of type `point` (i.e., `struct _point`), **not** 26 `point *`.

Change

```
vehicle = malloc(26*sizeof(point));
```

or, for better,

```
vehicle = malloc(26*sizeof * vehicle);
```

Otherwise, you're running short of allocated memory when you try to dererference the pointer to access `n`s of instances. So, you end up accessing out-of-bound memory which causes  [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, just an advice, if you know the size to be allocated beforehand, (`26`, for example), don't use dynamic memory, there's no need for it. Use an array.

Comment: Ah okay after reading some tutorials I must have confused arrays of structs and arrays of pointers to structs ^^ Thank you very much!

Comment: Or write self-documenting code: `malloc( sizeof(point[26]) )`.